# Swagger config for POST/PUT xml body

Tags: xml, post, swagger, put

I'd like to be able to define Swagger to represent POST/PUT requests with XML body.
There is an old screenshot that looks like it is/was possible:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/391

To be sure:
all relevant operation objects have "consumes": ["application/xml"]